# Upgrade existing realtime firebase database into Cloud Firestore

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, cloud, google-cloud-firestore

In one of my android application, I am using Firebase Realtime Database. Now, I want to upgrade existing data with new Cloud Firestore, So please let me know is that possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a duplicate question. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46639693/converting-firebase-database-to-cloud-firestore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly write code to copy your data from one place to another.  There is no automated process, since the two databases are designed very differently from each other.  You will need to make decisions about how to structure your collections and documents in Firestore, because Realtime Database has no such concepts.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/firestore-for-rtdb

Comment: The given link was very helpful to me. Thanks for the help..!